# How to style ListBoxItems like they are kept one behind another

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, styles, listboxitem

I have a listbox with large number of items. I would like to arrange the items in such a way, such that they look like they are arranged one behind another (as shown in the attached image), but not sure how to do it. I am working with Expression Blend. Please suggest me ways in which i can achieve this design. Any help is appreciated!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel) property of the ListBox (or [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611045)) to a panel that performs the desired layout.

Such a panel could be created by deriving from [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) and overriding the [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride) and [ArrangeOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride) methods.

Comment: Could you guide me a little more on this please?